# How to serve build folder in Koa?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, koa

I've written simple todo-app and I'm trying to deploy it to Heroku.
I deployed on heroku before, I used *Express + React*. In my server.js file, there was that piece of code:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

That piece of code serves 'build' folder if app is in production, and also sends 'index.html' to every request.

I need similar code but for *Koa + React*. Koa is very minimalistic framework, so I guess there must be additional packages installed, I don't know which ones. 
I tried *koa-send* and *koa-static*, but couldn't configure them. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this out right now but I think it would go something like this:

```js
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const send = require('koa-send');
const static = require('koa-static');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(static('./client/build'));

  router.get('*', async (ctx, next) => {
    try {
      await send(ctx, './client/build/index.html');
    } catch(err) {
      // TODO: handle err?
      return next();
    }
  });
}

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I was able to test this code now and it is working for me. Let me know if you have any other questions.